# How can I remove virus/application from Windows XP start up?

Tags: windows, virus

How can I remove the following virus/application from start up?

I tried to disable it from [MSConfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSConfig) but it didn't help.
It's not being detected by [Norton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_AntiVirus) or [Avast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avast!) antivirus solutions.

[image: Ghadeer al jabel compugters Removeal tool]

Comment: Try Autoruns from Sysinternals.

Comment: but my question remains same how to?, any command for " Autoruns from sysinternals "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can boot from [Avira Rescue CD](http://www.free-av.com/en/products/12/avira_antivir_rescue_system.html)
2. You can try and remove malware with [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)

Comment: okey I would like to try the way you've explained but why I'm not able to see it from MsConfig Utility as it couldn't found either on services nor on Startup Items....must be there is some other registry entry point from which it loads on windows startup.

Comment: @Japan -  That's because it's written to not show up. As is most malware.

Answer (score 0):

HijackThis might let you disable whatever it is that is running it, Malwarebytes as already recommended may also be able to detect it.  Usually if neither of those manage to help remove malware then I just give up and reformat, but you might be more stubborn and there may be removal instructions online - a Google search shows http://knowledgeoman.com/forums/showthread.php?t=8545 might help you.